# How Do I Keep My Writing Interesting?

Tags: fiction, description, getting-started

I'm a beginning writer, and I constantly find myself struggling with my own sentences. Sometimes I even find them boring and uninteresting which I know can be a serious killer if I want to keep my readers attention. Event though its simple drafts that I'm still working on, I also need pointers on how I can keep my text descriptive without going to over the top.

Here is an example of some of my text)

A gray eyed boy the Elites of the Imperium have been watching so carefully proved to be something else. Knowing he was from a family with an infamous history, they all couldn't decide if he was safe enough to be let through their gates.


"He's just sixteen," The bird masked lady said, her masked moved along with her eye brows as they raised, "Mabey he is stronger than us, but it doesn't make sense just to kill him."


The sigh of a more elderly man came from the other side of the roundtable, his gray hair poking out from the bag like cloth over his head. Even with his eyes hidden behind the two shadows of their sockets, it was evident his focus was on the lady across, "We do it to all the offenders, if not, they will most likely come back to kill." Resting a hand on the table, he took in another slow breath, "Mabey he could chance, but the Imperium is right to take the risk after what happened--"


Interrupted by another man behind a gold color jester face, the old man paused to hear what had to be said. "Give him another gun and who knows...he might turn on us." The jester scanned to room for any signs of agreement, "I don't trust a criminal, no matter the age. It seems as though you are taking pity just because its a first time offender at the age of sixteen, I think it doesn't matter about the age, a first time can also mean its not his last."


This is a sample from a few chapter in. If anyone can see some parts wrong with this, and give me any pointers, ill gladly appreciate it.